# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable (selenium 2.49)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

So, I'm trying to make a automatic scraper that is "user friendly". What I basically want it to do is, Scrape one page, click the button, scrape that page, click button. And have that loop as many as times as the user wants. (yes I know indent is off, I was testing some stuff.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

# Credit


# Vars
website_name = input("Webstie: ")
class_name = input("Class name: ")
button_xpath = input("what's the XPATH that you want to click (normally a button): ")
number_of_pages = int(input("How many pages would you like to scrape: "))

path = r"C:\Users\Skid\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(website_name + "")


def NormalScrape():
    for x in range(number_of_pages):
        time.sleep(5)
    print("1")
    posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(class_name)
    time.sleep(2)
    print("2")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('.' + button_xpath).click()
    for post in posts:
        print(post.text)

NormalScrape()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Skid/PycharmProjects/untitled/PureTest.py", line 34, in <module>
    NormalScrape()
  File "C:/Users/Skid/PycharmProjects/untitled/PureTest.py", line 31, in NormalScrape
    print(post.text)
  File "C:\Users\Skid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 71, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
  File "C:\Users\Skid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 454, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Skid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Skid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.111)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64)

Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x00F4DB10>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Skid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 136, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Skid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 120, in stop
  File "C:\Users\Skid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 95, in send_remote_shutdown_command
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 954, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 887, in _find_spec
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: maybe check `post` before you use `post.text` - maybe `post` is `None`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an existing bug in *Selenium 2.49 + Python 3 + Chrome*:

- [Problem with Python 3 + 2.49](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1476)

As a workaround, downgrade to `2.48`:

```
pip3 install selenium==2.48
```